# How do I get result of invoke direct?

Tags: reverse-engineering, bytecode, smali

1. I am trying to understand what is happening in the following smali code:
2. I am trying to log the result or stored value in key:

```
# creates new instance of SecretKeySpec in register v8
new-instance v8, Ljavax/crypto/spec/SecretKeySpec;

# store contant 0x0 in v0
const/4 v0, 0x0
aget-object v0, v9, v0

# store string AES in v1
const-string v1, "AES"

# calls new SecretKeySpec(v0,v1);
invoke-direct {v8, v0, v1}, Ljavax/crypto/spec/SecretKeySpec;-><init>([BLjava/lang/String;)V

.line 115
.local v8, "key":Ljavax/crypto/spec/SecretKeySpec;
```

Answer (score 2):

The invoke-direct call there is calling the constructor. Object creation in Java (and Dalvik) bytecode takes two instructions. The first, `new-instance` allocates an uninitialized object, while `invoke-direct` calls the constructor to initialize this object. The object is stored in v8, as you can see from the `new-instance` instruction.

Comment: Where would the line " .local v8, "key":Ljavax/crypto/spec/SecretKeySpec;" be generated from?

Comment: That is debug information, which is used to let a debugger know which register holds which variable in the original java source.